# Editing Question Minimum Criteria

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits

This happened to me in Super User and this basically a [re-post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7706/editing-question-minimum-critetia). I re-posted here since this could happen here as well. Feel free to delete the question if this topic has been already answered or found unnecessary.

I know there should be minimum 6 character altered during editing somebody's question. But what about the edits below in picture. Is it irresponsible editing or misuse of power of editing? Can somebody explain me this?

[image]

Comment: out of interest, as this happens very often and I have no clue why, where did you get the idea to use `backticks` for formatting individual words this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Backticks which make text `appear like this` are not a formatting option. They're not meant to emphasize text, they are meant to be used for inline code or commands like e.g. `ls -a *.txt` or similar things.

The original post misuses the backticks, they appear to mark completely random words without any purpose. The edit corrects this, which is a completely valid edit in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it irresponsible editing or misuse of power of editing?

No it's not irresponsible editing,he removed the hyphen's and also he changed small letter w for Windows to capital letter.Windows is an OS so it must start with a capital letter.

And also there is no 6 letters limitations for the Users who are above 2000 reputations.Even a single character edit would be applied.

[image]

He does this edit for post improvement.